# Log device info in DNNClassifier estimator in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, gpu

I am using `DNNClassifier` Estimator to train a binary classifier. I want to log device info to verify whether my model is running on GPU or CPU.

Since, with using Estimator we don't deal with `session`, how can I log device info?

Major Problem: My `3` layered neural net with hidden units `[100, 75, 50]` is running faster on CPU than GPU. I tried to increase batch size till 256 but still the same. Hence, I want to confirm whether it actually is using GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `config` argument of [`tf.estimator.Estimator.__init__`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#__init__):

```py
classifier = \
  DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                hidden_units=[100, 75, 50],
                config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(session_config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)))
```